# Why pictures of Google Photos also show in Picasa Web frontend?

Tags: google-photos, picasa-web-albums, upload

I know they now shut down Picasa as in favor for the new Google Photos. I never used Picasa, but now uploaded a few pictures lately to Google Photos.

But indeed when I visit https://picasaweb.google.com/home all the pictures from Google Photos show up there as well.

Is that a normal behaviour?
And more more point: Even though I only have very few albums created in Google Photos, in Picasa I see quite a lot of albums, named by dates. So for every date for which there are photos uploaded, one album is created in Picasa. Seems weird to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete.

Comment: Do whatever makes your ego bigger after 7years :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. Google Photos and Picasaweb (and presumably Google+ Photos) all simply use the same data store. I can't imagine that they would have wanted to copy all those petabytes of images from one place to another; better to just create a new app to point to the old data.

Comment: This answer is obsolete as Picasa Web Albums and Google+ Photos have been retired.